# How to left align a TabLayout title text?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

In every example I see the title text of the TabLayout is centered. I would like to align the text to the left.

This is the original: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUvCI.jpg)

This is what I want to achieve: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUOYi.jpg)

This is what I have right now: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO3Tr.jpg)

I have tried to set android:textAlignment="viewStart", android:foregroundGravity="left" but didn't work. Then I created a custom tablayout like in this question: [Android - tablayout with custom view tabs - drawable selector cannot be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890366/android-tablayout-with-custom-view-tabs-drawable-selector-cannot-be-applied) but it is still not on the left side exactly.

(Just a note: I don't want the tabs to be aligned, like here:  [How to make tab title alignment to left in TabLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142613/how-to-make-tab-title-alignment-to-left-in-tablayout-in-android), just the text inside the tab.)